# Move docker files to new installation

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Recently my Raspberry Pi 3b+ didn't boot correctly. I have decided to buy a new rpi 4 and wanted to transfer a Docker container (created with docker-compose) running Teslamate (self-hosted data logger for Tesla cars).

I have copied all the files of `/var/lib/docker` from the old SD, but actually I don't know how I can create again a container using all the previous data of Teslamate.

Additional informations:

- Teslamate is written in Elixir
- Data is stored in a Postgres database
- Visualization and data analysis with Grafana
- Vehicle data is published to a local MQTT Broker

Any clue?

Comment: For what it's worth, things are generally easier if you treat containers as ephemeral: if your docker host dies, you don't attempt to copy over containers; you just re-deploy them on your new server.

Comment: To add to @larsks's comment, you might have better luck re-creating the Docker containers on the new rpi and copying the Postgres data over using `pg_dump`.

Comment: @MrDiggles just the Postgres data?